# Python Rock Paper Scisssors Assigning String to random variable

Tags: python, string, random

I am writing a python rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock program for a class The computers pick is a random integer and the user is prompted to enter a number. It then displays the results and tells you who won. The program is running properly except for the print statement. I'm trying to get the program to show the computer pick and the user pick as the word instead of the number and I'm not sure of the best way to go about this. Currently, it prints the number as the answer. Any suggestions?

```
*computer = random.randint (0, 4)
user = eval(input("Enter a number between 0 and 4: O for scissors, 1 for paper, 2 for rock, 3 for lizard, 4 for Spock"))* 

*if computer == user:
    print("You tied, you both picked", user)
elif computer == 0 and user == 1:
    print("The computer picked ", computer, " you picked ", user, ". Computer wins!")*
```

***The computer picked  4  you picked  3 . You win!***

I'd like it to print as

***The computer picked scissors you picked rock. You win!***

Comment: Never use `eval()` with user input. Use `int()` to convert the input to a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can store a small list that contains the options like this:

```
options = ['scissors', 'paper', 'rock', 'lizard', 'Spock']
```

Then simply change your print statement to

```
print("The computer picked ", options[computer], " you picked ", options[user], ". Computer wins!")
```

Comment: Ok, can I make the computer pick one of the options at random? The reason I was using numbers was the computer answer is supposed to be picked at random and that is the only way we have been taught so far. This is my first Python class.

Comment: It still is random as you would still be using the `computer` variable which you assigned to a random integer (in the first line). All that `options[computer]` does is retrieve the string from the `options` list (from my answer) in the position of `computer` (i.e. 0 to 4). Enjoy the class!